# Custom Fields DB Design for Membership Application

Tags: sql, database-design

I need to design database for a membership application which needs custom classification for multiple organizations

Following are the data set:

- Organization type 1:
  Name, Email, Joining Year, End Year, Role, Location.
- Organization type 2:
  Name, Email, Joining Year, End Year, Role, Department, Sub Organization, Location
- Organization type 3:
  Name, Email, Joining Year, End Year, Role, Identification No.

what would be the best way to design database for it?
few field items are common, few are specific to org, org types are limited

#### Option 1:

- members_table - member_id, name, email, joining_year, end_year, role
- members_org_type_1 - member_id, location
- members_org_type_2 - member_id, department, sub_org, location
- members_org_type_3 - member_id, id_no

#### Option: 2

- members_table - member_id, name, email, joining_year, end_year, role
- member_fields - member_id, field_type, field_value
- field_labels - field_type, field_label

second type looks promising, but do not know how to do join operations members_table & member_fields with required fields?

Comment: Try the first option. No need to mess with EAV (that's the name for second option)

Comment: @ypercube please help me in understanding the difference, and which would be more efficient, right now, second option looks more flexible

Comment: Read this about option 2: [Is there a name for this database structure?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20759/is-there-a-name-for-this-database-structure) (that's mainly a view against it).

Comment: And here's the "pro" view (don't get confused by the title, it explains why and when can be used): [What is so bad about EAV, anyway?](https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway)

Comment: Thanks, will study them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem in database design and there are 3 most common ways to deal with (4 if we count EAV):

1. Three separate tables, one for each type.
2. One table - with a lot of columns - where some of them will be allowed to have Nulls. The integrity cannot be easily dealt by the database (which column combinations will be Null and which not) and are usually dealt by the application. This is @noa's answer and it results in slightly less code and probably easier to come up with a working (although not perfectly) application.
3. One `Member` table (this is the supertype) and 3 additional tables, one for each subtype. This allows you to have no Nulls and to enforce which columns will be used, depending on the organization type. (this is your Option 1)

You can also add an `org_type` column in all tables. This will mean an
additional `UNIQUE` constraint on `Member (org_type, member_ID)` and the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint (from each subtype table) altered to include this `org_type` column. Something like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE Member
    ( MemberID 
    , Org_Type
    , Name
    , ...
    , Role
    , PRIMARY KEY (MemberID)
    , UNIQUE KEY (Org_Type, MemberID)
    , CHECK Org_Type IN (1, 2, 3)
    ) ;

    CREATE TABLE Member_Type_1
    ( MemberID 
    , Org_Type
    , Location
    , PRIMARY KEY (MemberID)
    , FOREIGN KEY (Org_Type, MemberID)
        REFERENCES Member(Org_Type, MemberID) 
    , CHECK Org_Type = 1
    ) ;

and finally there's (your option 2) EAV:
```

4. [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model is, according to Wikipedia:

> a data model to describe entities where the number of attributes (properties, parameters) that can be used to describe them is potentially vast, but the number that will actually apply to a given entity is relatively modest. In mathematics, this model is known as a sparse matrix. EAV is also known as object–attribute–value model, vertical database model and open schema.

There are various reasons not to use EAV in relational databases, mainly because of problems regarding datatype and referential integrity (that cannot be easily enforced), difficulty in writing even simple queries (that end up written with a lot of joins) and efficiency. See the answer by Simon Righarts at DBA.SE question: [Is there a name for this database structure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20759/is-there-a-name-for-this-database-structure)

There are reasons that it's a valid option in certain cases though, as the article by Aaron Bertrand explains: [What is so bad about EAV, anyway?](https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway), especially when you have a lot of columns and even more when you don't know in advance what columns you will need (custom made by customers). That may be your case, if you want the organizations to be able to add custom columns.

Note however, that it's not easy to costruct an efficient EAV model/application. You are actually building an RDBMS inside a database.

Answer (score 2):

If org types are limited and rarely changing, just use one table:

- members_table - member_id, name, email, joining_year, end_year, role, location, department, sub_org, id_no

Use null values in the fields which aren't relevant to the organization type, and hide the non-applicable fields when you present the information.

I gave a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10640129/893113), though it was for a different database.

Comment: it would increase the number of columns a lot, coz.. the cols are many for each org type.

Comment: Agreed. There aren't enough specific fields to warrant splitting it up. The only thing I could suggest is adding an "organization type" field to be able to filter results easily. You could then use a trigger to make sure the appropriate fields are filled in or stay null when they should be, based on the type.

Comment: @Masade You are only talking 4 additional columns. Worst case is 3 are NULL; best case is 1 is NULL.

Comment: Worst case is 4 Nulls, best case is 2 Nulls.

Comment: @ypercube For organization type 2, only "Identification No" would be null.

Comment: Yeah, ok, location is in 2 types, ok.

Comment: ok... do we have any general rule on when to use which model?

Comment: but the i have told is just a sample.. i have have atleast 8-10 cols in each org type... 4-5 may be common

Comment: The examples you gave look simple – a small number of added fields, some of which are shared. You're talking about adding *an entire table* for each of these types, which means unique insert/update/delete code depending on the org type. If you have a couple org types which have, say, eight unique fields each, I'd consider putting those values in a separate table, but for the small number of fields here splitting them out increases the complexity but produces little value.

Comment: There will be unique inserts/updates for each type, whatever the chosen deisgn.

Comment: Surely that would depend on the framework or application architecture. After the application handles the subtype-specific checks, with a one-table design or option 2 above, the database code could be generalized to handle the insert/update without modification based on the subtype.